# How to validate nested objects with generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-inference

I have a generic type like this:

```
type Item<T> = {a:T; B:T}
```

So I want to infer an object with agreed fields type without specifying a generic type:

```
const items: Record<string, Item<?>> = {
first: {a:1, b:2},
second: {a:'asd'; b:'asd'}
third: {a:1; b:'qwe'} // error should here because generic isn't agreed
} as const
```

Comment: This has a significant number of typos.  Could you fix them so that this is a [mre]? You should test it in an IDE to make sure.

Comment: Also note, `items` could be of type `{a: Item<number>, b: Item<string>, c: Item<string | number>}`; if that's not acceptable, then can you clarify that you only want to infer from `a` and not both `a` and `b`?

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way (TS doesn't have so-called *existential types* which is what you'd need).  So you need a generic type and a generic helper like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnKDvm).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm  missing.

Comment: @jcalz yes, that's it! I'm also interested in how to implement support for multiple generics in the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. You'd have to have the possible types beforehand for `Item` though.

```js
type Item<T> = {a:T; b:T}

// Define the possible types
type StringItem = Item<string>
type NumberItem = Item<number>

// Use union on all of them
type Items =
  | StringItem
  | NumberItem

// And the error pop up on the right place
const items: Record<string, Items> = {
  first: {a:1, b:2},
  second: {a:'asd', b:'asd'},
  third: {a:1, b:'qwe'} // error should here because generic isn't agreed
} as const
```